# What does "Host key did not appear in manually configured list" mean?

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm trying to set up an SSH key pair. I have so far I have

1. Generated the pair with PuTTYGen
2. Saved the private key to the client machine
3. Added the public key to server. I put it in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user that I will be using to connect
4. Added the fingerprint from PuTTYGen to the *Connection > SSH > Host Keys* menu in PuTTY
5. Added the path of the private key to the *Connection > SSH > Auth menu in PuTTY*

But when I try to connect I get the error *"Host key did not appear in manually configured list"*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The step 4 is wrong:

> Added the fingerprint from PuTTYGen to the Connection > SSH > Host Keys menu in PuTTY

The [*"Host keys"* box](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-kex-manual-hostkeys) is for public key of the *server* (*host* key). While you have added there *your* public key.

In general, you do not need to add anything there. Just verify the host key on the prompt, that you will get on the first connection. What you have probably done already anyway. If not, see *my article* [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey) – You can also check another article [Understanding SSH Key Pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).